# How to wire up a controller's dependancy

Tags: c#, nhibernate, castle-windsor

So I went through the asp.net mvc tutorial for castle windsor, and my registrations look like:

```
    private static IWindsorContainer _container = new WindsorContainer();
    private static void BootstrapContainer()
    {
        _container = new WindsorContainer()
            .Install(FromAssembly.This());
        var controllerFactory = new WindsorControllerFactory(_container.Kernel);
        ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(controllerFactory);
    }
    protected void Application_End()
    {
        _container.Dispose();
    }
```

So in my HomeController I have this:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IUserService _userService;

    public HomeController(IUserService userService)
    {
        this._userService = userService;
    }
}
```

How would I go about wiring this controller up to setup the IUserService?

**Update**
In case in matters how I need to wire things up, my vs.net projects are:

```
web, interfaces, entities, data (nhibernate), services
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The implementation of WindsorControllerFactory should look like this from the doco http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Windsor-tutorial-part-two-plugging-Windsor-in.ashx?HL=ikernel.

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory 
{ 
   private readonly IKernel kernel; 

   public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel) 
   { 
       this.kernel = kernel; 
   } 

   public override void ReleaseController(IController controller) 
   { 
       kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller); 
   } 

   protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) 
   { 
       if (controllerType == null) 
       { 
           // Throw exception. Can't resolve null type.
       }

       return (IController)kernel.Resolve(controllerType);
   } 
}
```

**UPDATED**

Each interface that needs to be resolved by dependancy injection need to be registered.

This can be done by calling the .Register method on the container.

```
container.Register(Component.For<IUserService>().ImplementedBy<UserService>().LifeStyle.Transient);
```

More info here: http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-one-by-one.ashx

Comment: I was hoping to autowire all Services, and then autowire all components for a controller.  how can i do that?

Comment: @Blankman To do this you should create a marker interface like IService with no implementation and inherit IUserService from it. Then call container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly().BasedOn<IService>().WithService.FromInterface()); This will register all the IServices. Alternatively you should build an installer class. http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Installers.ashx and http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.Registering-components-by-conventions.ashx. I probally wouldn't register everthing from one call because the lifetime will likely need to be handled differently.